# Remove parent row if match found in child row, mysql UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have two tables 
Let's called them table schedule and table appointments

**Schedule table:**

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  3 |
| 42 |
+----+
```

**Appointment table:**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | schedule_id |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |           0 |
|  2 |          42 |
+----+-------------+
```

I have a query that gets appointments and schedules out of the database it looks something similar to this:

```
SELECT id FROM appointment 
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM schedule
```

I want to get all schedules and appointments, if there's an appointment that has a matching schedule_id I want the schedule row to be removed from the results

The end result would be

```
+----+-------------+
| id | schedule_id |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |           0 |
|  2 |          42 |
|  3 |           0 |
+----+-------------+
```

What do I need to do to create that query?

Comment: `if there's an appointment that has a matching schedule_id I want the schedule row to be removed from the results`: Does that means you've removed row with `id=42` from end result?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: I guess answers given below should work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
select a.id, a.schedule_id
from appointment a
union all
select s.id, 0
from schedule s 
where not exists (select 1 from appointment a where a.id = s.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibility:

```
select id, schedule_id from
  (
  select id, 0 as schedule_id from schedule
  union
  select id, schedule_id from appointment
  ) t
  where id not in (select distinct schedule_id from appointment);
```